# Strange division results in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, division

I think there is some inconsistency in the division operation, but I am not sure.

In the following code I would expect either a//c to be 100.0, or b//c to be -99.0.

```
a = 1.0
b = -1.0
c = 0.01

print (a/c)
print (a//c)
print (b/c)
print (b//c)
```

gives:

```
100.0
99.0
-100.0
-100.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the way [floating point numbers are represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). It's not true that `1.0` is exactly 100 times `0.01` (as far as floating points are represented internally). The operator `//` performs division and floors the result so it may be that internally the number is slightly less than `100.0` and this leads it to being floored to `99.0`.

Furthermore, Python 3.x uses [a different approach](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580) to showing you the floating point number as compared to Python 2.x. This means the result of `1.0 / 0.01`, although internally slightly less than `100.0`, will be displayed to you as `100.0` because the algorithm determined that the number is close enough to `100.0` to be considered equal to `100.0`. This is why `1.0 / 0.01` is shown to you as `100.0` even though this may not be represented internally as exactly that number.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Even though the logic is clear - this behavior is misleading in such an intuitive operation.

Comment: @Baba: perhaps but this is one of the caveats of using floating point numbers. There are way more floating point numbers than a computer could hope to represent accurately so this is something to be aware of when using floating point numbers.